# How do I speed up a script based on a grep search?

Tags: shell-script, text-processing, grep

There is a very large text file with two comma-separated values:

```
78414387,10033
78769989,12668
78771319,13677
78771340,13759
80367563,16336
81634533,10025
82878571,10196
110059366,10218
110059411,10812
110059451,10067
```

I need to search for these values in a log file which is looking like so:

```
- delivery-AMC_prod_product 231825855936862016-07-02 00:00:52 c.c.i.d.s.d.DeliveryTopologyFactory$$anon$1$$anon$2 [INFO] ack: uid=57773c737e3d80d7def296c7| id=278832702| version=28| timestamp=1467432051000
- delivery-AMC_prod_product 231825855936862016-07-02 00:00:52 c.c.i.d.s.d.DeliveryTopologyFactory$$anon$1$$anon$2 [INFO] ack: uid=57773c732f18c26fe604fd04| id=284057302| version=9| timestamp=1467432051000
- delivery-AMC_prod_product 231825855936862016-07-02 00:00:52 c.c.i.d.s.d.DeliveryTopologyFactory$$anon$1$$anon$2 [INFO] ack: uid=57773c747e3d80d7def296c8| id=357229| version=1151| timestamp=1467432052000
- delivery-AMC_prod_product 231825855936862016-07-02 00:00:52 c.c.i.d.s.d.DeliveryTopologyFactory$$anon$1$$anon$2 [INFO] ack: uid=57773c742f18c26fe604fd05| id=279832706| version=35| timestamp=1467432052000
- delivery-AMC_prod_product 231825855936862016-07-02 00:00:52 c.c.i.d.s.d.DeliveryTopologyFactory$$anon$1$$anon$2 [INFO] ack: uid=57773c744697ddb976cf5a95| id=354171| version=503| timestamp=1467432052000
- delivery-AMC_prod_product 231825855936862016-07-02 00:00:53 c.c.i.d.s.d.DeliveryTopologyFactory$$anon$1$$anon$2 [INFO] ack: uid=57773c754697ddb976cf5a96| id=355638| version=1287| timestamp=1467432053000
```

My script:

```
#!/bin/bash
COUNT=0
while IFS=',' read ID VERSION; do
    VERSION=`echo $VERSION |col -bx`
    if (grep "id=${ID}| version=$VERSION" worker-6715.log.2016-$1.log.* > /dev/null); then
            let "COUNT++"
    else
            echo "$ID, $VERSION FAIL"
            exit 2

    fi
done < recon.txt

echo "All OK, $COUNT checked"
```

- If I cut off unnecessary fields from the log file, would this speed the execution up?
- If I create a RAM device and copy the logfile there, would this speed the execution up or is my [Red Hat Linux 6](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_Hat_Linux#Version_history) (Hedwig) caching the file anyway?
  Any other suggestions?

Comment: Your pattern seems to match but if you could use `-E` to match it explicitly then that would speed up too.

Comment: @Niranjan the `|` is part of the pattern, not an OR.

Comment: What does the `...| col -bx` achieve?  It spawns a subshell and an external process, each time round the loop, but doesn't look like it should have any effect on `VERSION`.

Comment: Your problem seems very close to https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/man.html#EXAMPLE:-Grepping-n-lines-for-m-regular-expressions

Comment: It will be good to know how big the files are compared to the available memory. If one of the files can fit in RAM it can change the best algorithm dramatically.

Answer (score 5):

Your bottleneck is reading the `recon.txt` file line by line in the shell.  To get the failing lines you could preprocess the lines in the logs to look like the lines in `recon.txt`, then use `comm(1)` to find the set difference, perhaps like this:

```
comm -23 \
    <(sort -u recon.txt) \
    <(sed 's/.*| id=\([0-9]*\)| version=\([0-9]*\)|.*/\1,\2/' worker-6715.log.2016-$1.log.* | \
        sort -u)
```

This assumes a shell that can handle `<(...)` constructs.  Also, please note that the lines in the result don't preserve the order of the lines in `recon.txt`.  Keeping that order would be a lot harder (and slower).

If you also need the success counts you can do it the other way around, preprocess `recon.txt` so that it looks like what might be found in the logs, then use `fgrep(1)` or `grep -F` to do the search.  Setting locales to `C` can also speed up things substantially on some systems.  Thus:

```
COUNT=$( \
    sed 's/\([0-9]*\),\([0-9]*\)/| id=\1| version=\2|/' recon.txt | \
    LC_ALL=C fgrep -f - worker-6715.log.2016-$1.log.* | \
    wc -l )
```

This assumes that `recon.txt` doesn't contain duplicates, and that each line in `recon.txt` matches at most once across all the logs.  Lifting the first restriction would be hard.  The second could be lifted with a carefully chosen `comm(1)`.

Comment: @terdon Please.  `fgrep` has been working fine for 40 years.  It isn't going away any time soon, regardless of what agenda the GNU people are trying to push.  Also, `fgrep = grep -F`, not `grep -f`.

Comment: Fair point about `-f`, that was a typo, my bad. As for the rest, it has nothing to do with GNU, it's [POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/grep.html). Yes, I know it's been around for years and is likely to go on being so for a while but there's no reason to force the new generation to use our bad habits. The `grep -F` is preferred and recommended by POSIX so why not get used to using it?

Comment: @terdon Because historically `fgrep` and `grep` are very different beasts.  `fgrep` was based on Aho–Corasick, while `grep` was based on regexps.

Comment: OK. And why is that remotely relevant 20 or more years down the line? The current (and previous) version of the POSIX specs clearly defines `grep -F` and states that "The *old* [emphasis mine] egrep and fgrep commands are likely to be supported for many years to come as implementation extensions". Why continue to use the old way when the standards have changed? Why continue to produce legacy code and force devs to support obsolete commands? We should move with the times or, at least, update our recommendations with the times.

Comment: So?  Does anyone actually use a stand-alone `fgrep` any more (i doubt it)? or is it just a hard or symbolic link to `grep`?  Surprisingly, GNU `fgrep` is a wrapper sh script around `exec grep -F "$@"` (I assumed it would be a link...so GNU `fgrep` has the overhead of forking a shell and IFS splitting the args again  **UUOfgrep**!).

Comment: In the second method, you could use `grep -c` (also in POSIX) instead of passing it on to `wc`.

Comment: @JigglyNaga Not really.  `grep -c` counts each line matched, and supposedly there are many of those.  The OP wants the grand total, and `grep -c` doesn't provide that.

Comment: @SatoKatsura .  Oh, I hadn't realised that there could be multiple log files.  You could cat all the log files together and pipe that to grep (so that it counts them all as one), but then you'd have to put the patterns in a temp file as the argument for `-f`, and that's not simplifying things any more.

Comment: Hmm.  Reading the OP's example again, it seems they don't want to count total lines matched, either.  They want a count of the number of log files that contained any matches - in which case, add `-l` to the `grep` options, and pipe to `wc -l` as before.

Comment: @JigglyNaga `COUNT` is the number of lines _from `recon.txt`_ that matches in at least one of the logs.

Comment: @SatoKatsura Your example produces the total number of lines, in all of the log files, that matched something from `recon.txt`.  If 2 lines from `recon.txt` are found in 5 log files, 10 times each, that `grep` command will display all 100 of them.  It's only the same if every ID+VERSION pair has only one match across all log files.

Comment: @JigglyNaga Hence the note about assumptions.

Comment: Oops, sorry, I think I read everything out of order there.

Comment: Sato briefly mentioned setting LC_ALL=C but this is very important in a grep on large files.  See http://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/website/ssh/speed-up-grep-searches-with-lc-all for details. As discussed above, use grep -F (not fgrep) if your search string is not a regex for a performance boost.

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out, the main problem here is the shell loop. I'd use `awk` to process the log file first, joining the `id` and `version` values and saving the result into an array then read `recon.txt` and on each line check if it's in array, if not - save the line content in a variable `t` and `exit` immediately (executing the `END` block). In the `END` block, if there's a line saved in `t` then `exit 2` with a message, else just print the OK message with no. of lines of `recon.txt`:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{j=$9","$10;gsub(/[^0-9,]/, "", j);a[j]++;next}
!($0 in a){t=$0;{exit}}
END{if (t){print t, "FAIL"; exit 2}
else{print "All OK,", FNR, "checked"}}' logfile recon.txt
```

This assumes numerical values for the `id` and `version` and that they're always in 9th and respectively 10th field. If that's not the case you could use a regex like *Sato* does - that is, if your `awk` flavor supports backreferences otherwise something like this would do:

```
NR==FNR{sub(/.* id=/, "");sub(/\| version=/, ",");sub(/\|.*/, ""));a[$0]++;next}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd put these files into DB (any type you like). Perhaps even not import the large file, but put line-by-line from your app which generates that output.

Then the DB engine will not waste resources to call grep each time but use internal function compiled from C.

Don't forget to create indexes after import (if you importing the whole file) or after table creation (if you insert records row-by-row).

Answer (score 0):

First convert recon.txt to a format that is fast to use for grep -F:

```
perl -pe 's/,/| version=/' recon.txt > recon.grep-F
```

Then your situation is as described on https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/parallel_examples.html#example-grepping-n-lines-for-m-regular-expressions

Here the text is adapted for your problem:

The simplest solution to grep a big file for a lot of regexps is:

```
grep -f regexps.txt bigfile
```

Or if the regexps are fixed strings:

```
grep -F -f recon.grep-F worker.log
```

There are 2 limiting factors: CPU and disk I/O. CPU is easy to measure: If the grep takes >90% CPU (e.g. when running top), then the CPU is a limiting factor, and parallelization will speed this up. If not, then disk I/O is the limiting factor, and depending on the disk system it may be faster or slower to parallelize. The only way to know for certain is to measure.

If the CPU is the limiting factor parallelization should be done on the regexps:

```
cat recon.grep-F | parallel --pipe -L1000 --round-robin grep -F -f - worker.log
```

If a line matches multiple regexps, the line may be duplicated. The command will start one grep per CPU and read bigfile one time per CPU, but as that is done in parallel, all reads except the first will be cached in RAM. Depending on the size of regexp.txt it may be faster to use --block 10m instead of -L1000. If regexp.txt is too big to fit in RAM, remove --round-robin and adjust -L1000. This will cause bigfile to be read more times.

Some storage systems perform better when reading multiple chunks in parallel. This is true for some RAID systems and for some network file systems. To parallelize the reading of bigfile:

```
parallel --pipepart --block 100M -a worker.log -k grep -F -f recon.grep-F
```

This will split bigfile into 100MB chunks and run grep on each of these chunks. To parallelize both reading of bigfile and regexp.txt combine the two using --fifo:

```
parallel --pipepart --block 100M -a worker.log --fifo cat recon.grep-F \
\| parallel --pipe -L1000 --round-robin grep -f - {}
```

If a line matches multiple regexps, the line may be duplicated.

Answer (score 0):

You're performing the query "all from set A that are not in set B", in addition to transforming one set to be in the same format as the other.  Most approaches to this require, at some level, nested loops.

In your version, you're using `grep` for the inner loop (testing every line in the logs), and `bash` for the outer one (every line in `recon.txt`).  The `bash` loop spawns several subshells and processes each time round, which is slow.  Each `grep` handles the inner loop internally, but still requires a new process each time.

The following line spawns three new processes (two subshells and `col`) each time round the outer loop:

```
VERSION=`echo $VERSION |col -bx`
```

And it's not clear what purpose it serves.  If it is necessary, you should try to put the `col` outside the loop, so that it filters all of `recon.txt` in a single process.  See also [Why is using a shell loop to process text considered bad practice?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice).

[Sato Katsura's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/293758/90751) avoids the nested loop by sorting both sets of input, storing them in temporary files, and then using `comm`.  With the restriction that the inputs are sorted, `comm` doesn't have to use nested loops.

However, for large input files, the temporary files will also be large (`recon.txt` gets reordered, ie. output is the same size as its input; the log files are cut down to the same format and reordered).  And there's the sort time itself - [`sort` uses mergesort](https://superuser.com/questions/234054/unix-sort-algorithm-implementation), which is at worst *O(n log n)*.

If you want to avoid temporary files and sorting, you can let `grep` handle both loops:

```
cat worker-6715.log.2016-$1.log.* |
 sed 's/.*| id=\([0-9]*\)| version=\([0-9]*\)|.*/\1,\2/' |
 grep -F -x -v -f - recon.txt || ( echo -n "Lines OK: " ; wc -l < recon.txt)
```

As before, a single invocation of `sed` (copied from that answer) transforms the log format into the `recon.txt` format.  Then `grep -v` reports only those lines of recon.txt that *weren't* found in the logs.  `-f -` takes the reformatted logs from standard input (avoiding temporary files, but meaning that `grep` has to hold them all in memory).  `-F` to match fixed strings rather than patterns, `-x` to match only whole lines.

As `grep` has been inverted to report non-matches, it will return "success" if there were any lines not found.  So the `||` will only display the message and total count if all lines were found.